# Stimulsoft Report Section Control in C#

Tags: c#, report, stimulsoft

i use Stimulsoft Report to Make Reports in My Program (C# Program).

I want to Change (or Control) Visibility One Section (e.g. Footer Band) in Report From C# Code.

How Do this?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should create a variable inside the report and pass a value from C#.
Then inside the report you could use the variable to decide if printing or not your section.
For example:

```
            bool printFooterValue = false;
            using(StiReport rpt = new StiReport())
            {
                rpt.Load("your_report_file.mrt);
                rpt.Dictionary.Databases.Clear();
                rpt.Dictionary.Databases.Add(new StiOleDbDatabase("your_database", "your_connection_string"));
                rpt.Compile();
                rpt.CompiledReport["printFooter"] = printFooterValue;
                if(preview == true)
                    rpt.Show(true);
                else
                    rpt.Print(false, 1);
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the Footer via GetComponents and then enable or disable it in code.

E.g.

```
var myFooter = rpt.GetComponents()["FooterName"];
myFooter.Enabled = false;
```